# Creating a razor dynamic html table in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, rss

I'm trying to display RSS news items in a row three at a time. I can currently display each item one in each row at a time using the code:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.RSSFeed)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.Raw(item.Description)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

I tried to use two loop statements but could not get it to not break the code. How would someone use a loop statement to dynamically generate the contents in a RSS feed in a three items row at a time?

Comment: Couldn't understand what's wrong with your code, it looks good what's the issue?

Comment: The code you mentioned looks fine what is the issuse? Do you mean you want to show it side by side in one row?

Comment: I guess OP is trying to display 3 columns per row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be easily achieved using a list and css rules rather than a table:

```
<ul>
    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.RSSFeed)
    {
        <li>
            @Html.Raw(item.Description)
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul li {
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
}

ul li:nth-child(3n + 4) {
    clear: left;
    float: left;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/1zaefv0h/)

Comment: This is NOT a great solution as it breaks when the <li> elements are of different length.

Answer (score 2):

You can use simple `for loop` instead of `foreach` loop to achieve goal.

```
@{var items = ViewBag.RSSFeed;}
@for (int i = 0; i < items.Count(); i++)
{ 
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.Raw(items[i].Description)
    </td>
    @{i++;}

    @if (i < items.Count())
    {
        <td>
            @Html.Raw(items[i].Description)
        </td>
    }
    @{i++;}

    @if (i < items.Count())
    {
        <td>
            @Html.Raw(items[i].Description)
        </td>
    }
</tr>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this work? Cannot post it as a comment and I assumed the same what @Zabavsky  said.

```
  @{var i = 0;
  var idx = 0;
  var j = 2;}
<table>
    @while (i <= j)
    {
        <tr>
            @while (idx < ViewBag.RssFeed.Length && i <= j)
            {
                <td>
                    @Html.Raw(ViewBag.RssFeed[idx]);
                    @{idx++; i++;}

                    i++;
                </td>
            }
            @{j += 3;
            }
            @if (idx >= ViewBag.RssFeed.Length)
            {
                break;
            }
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

This is just a sample

Modified: This will print 3 per row. But @Zabavsky's solution seems better

Following is a sample output

[image]